# react npm configuration not setting up correct

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I try to run npm run-script build on my project after downloading git and node and it says that it cannot find module when the module is there in the folder, package.lock file includes react scripts as well. I am new to react and just starting out if anyone has experiences this issue before how did you manage to solve?
[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Eeb.jpg)

Comment: can you post your error?

Comment: its not letting me upload photos but one of the error says 'react-scripts not found' and another error says 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'